# How to make file availabe to android app at exactly midnight respective to their time zone

Tags: android, timezone, utc, current-time

I have a server configured to time zone IST which is GMT+5:30 and on everyday new JSON file will be generated using Cron job. Generated filename would be 1551139200000.json ie.GMT: Tuesday, February 26, 2019 12:00:00 AM.

How to make this file available to android app only on/after 12:00AM. Currently it could be available to all time-zone which were not hit 12:00 AM. In this case it should access previous day's Json file.

```
// normal code here.
long fullMsecs = System.currentTimeMillis();
long ist_offset = 330*60*1000;

long filename = (fullMsecs + ist_offset)/86400_000 * 86400_000;
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:filename" + filename);

// filename would be affixed with required file extension.
```

PS: this logic is available in famous crossword like puzzle Bonza. In that game new puzzle will be accessed on start-of-the-day ie, 12:00 AM.

Comment: So if the users want the new file early, they can just set their device time zone to Pacific/Kiritimati (which is GMT+14:00)? Would you be able to detect such cheating?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just to avoid auto accessing file even though device time NOT yet reached the midnight.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    // Today in user’s time zone
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    // Today’s file name is epoch millis for 12 AM GMT
    long startOfDayGmt = today.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
    String fileName = String.valueOf(startOfDayGmt) + ".json";

    System.out.println("File name: " + fileName);
```

Output when running just now is what you had expected:

> File name: 1551139200000.json

Don’t do date and time calculations by hand as in your question. It’s harder than you think, error-prone and hard to read and maintain. java.time, the modern Java date and time API, offers very nice facilities for what you need.

### Question: Can I use java.time with Android minSdkVersion 19?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: my app's build config is like `compileSdkVersion 26` `minSdkVersion 19` and `targetSdkVersion 26` . So I couldn't use ZoneId for api 19. But your code is flawless which I tested by changing api level and will use in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, @kiranking. I changed the header to *Question: Can I use java.time with Android minSdkVersion 19?* in an attempt to make it clearer that I already tried to address that in the answer. :-)